# jQuery syntax error - unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

I'm trying to debug and I keep getting a syntax error. I'm not sure what is going on with this. I'm trying to have it where if I click on an object which is attached to "$color_cell" it pushes the atrr("id") into the black_colors array.

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ids = [];
var black_colors = [];
var blue_colors = [];
var brown_colors = [];
var gray_colors = [];
var green_colors = [];
var orange_colors = [];
var pink_colors = [];
var purple_colors = [];
var red_colors = [];
var teal_colors = [];
var white_colors = [];
var yellow_colors = [];


$(document).ready(function($) {


    $(".btnColor").click(function(){

        $(".color_cell").click(function(){

            if $(this).attr("id") == "black"{

            black_colors.push($(this).attr("id"));

    }

        });

    });

});

</script>
<br>
<br>
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="black">Black</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="blue">Blue</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="brown">Brown</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="gray">Gray</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="green">Green</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="orange">Orange</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="pink">Pink</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="purple">Purple</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="red">Red</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="teal">Teal</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="white">White</button>&nbsp;
    <button type="button" class="btnColor" id="yellow">Yellow</button>&nbsp;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many errors in your code.

```
<script src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

should become:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
```

should become:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

and:

```
if $(this).attr("id") == "black"{
```

should become:

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "black") {
```

And also you have nested the two `.click()` handlers which is not correct.

so that finally you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var ids = [];
var black_colors = [];
var blue_colors = [];
var brown_colors = [];
var gray_colors = [];
var green_colors = [];
var orange_colors = [];
var pink_colors = [];
var purple_colors = [];
var red_colors = [];
var teal_colors = [];
var white_colors = [];
var yellow_colors = [];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".color_cell").click(function() {
        // Can't see any color_cell class in your markup
        // so no idea what you want to do if the DOM element with it is clicked
    });

    $(".btnColor").click(function() {
        if ($(this).attr("id") == "black") {
            black_colors.push($(this).attr("id"));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Only the last one is a real error. Default scripting language in HTML5 is JavaScript (ok, we don't know if it is HTML5) and the jQuery passes a reference to itself as first argument to the ready handler.

Answer (score 3):

instead of : if $(this).attr("id") == "black"

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == "black")
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your javascript syntax is quite right.  Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".btnColor").click(function(){
        $(".color_cell").click(function(){
            if ($(this).attr("id") == "black") {
               black_colors.push($(this).attr("id"));
             }
        });
    });
});
```